# Hiding UIButton when pushed, then showing it when another button is pushed

Tags: ios, swift

I have three buttons that change the colour of my background. I want to hide the RED button when it's pushed. The show it if GREEN or BLUE button is pushed.
The same goes for the GREEN and BLUE buttons.

I can't find a way to call `removeFromSuperview`. In ObjectiveC I used to do `mybutton.hidden = true`
but this doesn't work.

```
ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func RED(_ sender: Any) {

    print("background was \(String(describing: self.view.backgroundColor))")
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    print("background is now \(String(describing: self.view.backgroundColor))")
}

@IBAction func GREEN(_ sender: Any) {
    print("background was \(String(describing: self.view.backgroundColor))")
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    print("background is now \(String(describing: self.view.backgroundColor))")
}

@IBAction func BLUE(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("background was \(String(describing: self.view.backgroundColor))")
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    print("background is now \(String(describing: self.view.backgroundColor))")
}
```

Comment: You should be able to do `button.isHidden = true`? If it works in ObjC it should also work (with translation) in Swift.

Comment: hmm. maybe Im doing something wrong! i´ll try again.

Comment: nope i tried again, get UIButton has no member "ishidden"

Comment: @Splenso It's `isHidden`, not `ishidden`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an IBOutlet for each button in order to access the "isHidden" property.  Right now you only have an IBAction defined for each (at least in the code you've provided).  To create the IBOutlet, control-drag from the button to your view controller's code, similar to what you did to create the IBActions you already have.  In the popup, make sure that "Connection" says "Outlet" and "Type" is "UIButton".  Name them as desired (e.g., redButton, blueButton).  Then you can type "redButton.isHidden = true" in the appropriate location.

An IBAction only allows you to control what the button will do when it is pressed.  An IBOutlet is required to access the properties of a UIButton.

Comment: Wow! It works! thank you for the well written answer ;)